# How to make a HTML heading look like a link

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line of HTML which basically opens a popup window on the same page. This works fine - however, because the HTML uses a heading, it isnt obvious that you can click on it. Does anyone know how I can make the heading look like a link?

Here is the line:

```
<h3 class="link" onclick="displayPopup(\'' + id+ '\');">' + CLICK HERE!! + '</h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML is the presentation of semantical structure.

If you define a `<h3>` it **IS** a heading, **not** a link.
If you define a `<a>` it **IS** a link, **not** a heading.

**Do not misuse those!**
It could have drastical negativ affect on SEO and usability.

If you want to style an entity, you'd use CSS.

A link has an underlined text on hover etc,..:

```
.link { cursor: pointer; color: blue; }
.link:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: and `color: blue;` too

Comment: He said the h3 opens a popup, so there's no SEO concern here.

Comment: @DarkoRomanov To be honest, I'm not exactly sure about it. Google is able to recognize `onclick` of course and as a heading is not intended to have an action like href or popup, I can imagine they lower the ranking. Misusing HTML actually is bad practice and, altho I cannot provide a proof of evidence, I think it has negative affects due to search engine ranking algorithms.

Comment: I'm not sure about that at all. Google doesn't open the popup, so using a A tag in this case it can't affect the ranking. I would call "misusing" some technique to hijack user clicks, for example. But think again about the A to open a popup: what href would you use? Hash? Empty? Anything else? In any case there's nothing that tells to Google: this A opens that popup, and even in that case Google wouldn't read the content of a popup.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple row of CSS

```
.link { cursor:pointer; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add this to your css to change pointer and underline the text.

```
.link {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the class "link" a hover-effect like so:

```
h3.link:hover {
  color: #339933;
  text-decoraction: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

(you may or may not want to have "link" only work on h3`s, that depends on your case)

I do, however, suggest that instead of using a heading and make it look like a link, you might instead want to use a link and make it look more like a heading.

I cannot quite explain why, but I feel that this is the more proper action to take here, judging from the function you want the element to perform.